# Error instantiating Typescript Class (Error not a constructor)

Tags: typescript

I am new to TypeScript and am having trouble with basic class instantiation.

I have a namespace RecordsService with class Record declared inside of it. I want to be able to create Records within RecordsService, then access them via public methods from other methods and such.

```
export namespace RecordsService {

    let records: Array<Record> = new Array();

    function init () {
        let record1 = new Record(new Date(), 1);
    }
    init();

    export function getAllRecords() {
        return records;
    }

    class Record {

        constructor (public date: Date, public id: number) {
            this.date = date;
            this.id = id;
        }
    }
}
```

The above doesn't throw any transpiling error but when ran I get a console error with the below

> TypeError: Record is not a constructor(…)

line that errors is `let record1 = new Record(new Date(), 1);`
How can I create a new Record in this case?

Plunker, view console log to see error: https://plnkr.co/edit/FNk8b1ZwA5HL3I7wAnTq?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your `Record` class to be above the `init` function:

```
class Record {
    constructor (public date: Date, public id: number) {
        this.date = date;
        this.id = id;
    }
}

let records: Array<Record> = new Array();

function init () {
    let record1 = new Record(new Date(), 1);
}
init();
```

Or call the `init` function after the definition of `Record`:

```
let records: Array<Record> = new Array();

function init () {
    let record1 = new Record(new Date(), 1);
}

export function getAllRecords() {
    return records;
}

class Record {
    constructor (public date: Date, public id: number) {
        this.date = date;
        this.id = id;
    }
}

init();
```

The reason why this happens is that javascript is an interpreted language, the interpreter parses the code line after the other, and so it reaches the `init()` part (in you original code) before it interpreted the `Record` class.

The content of the `init` function isn't interpreted until you execute the function which is why it's safe to have it before the class definition and just execute it afterwards.

Also, if you're doing this:

```
constructor (public date: Date, public id: number)
```

Then there's no need to do this:

```
this.date = date;
this.id = id;
```

It's either:

```
class Record {
    constructor (public date: Date, public id: number) {}
}
```

Or

```
class Record {
    public date: Date;
    public id: number;

    constructor (date: Date, id: number) {
        this.date = date;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, love when errors are silly things I know but didn't think of